# How can I make sure all items in the useState array are unique im using local Storage and I have multiple of the same items getting stored in the ls

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-state

```
const [watchList, setWatchlist] = React.useState([])

 React.useEffect(() => {
  setWatchlist(ls('myList'))
  
 },[])
 function setWatchListAction(mylist) {
    setWatchlist(mylist)
 }
  

 const addToMyList = (media) => {
// Heres where i add my data 
  let myList;
  if(ls("myList") !== null){
    myList = ls("myList")
    myList.push(media)
    ls.set("myList", myList)
    setWatchlist(myList)
   
    
  } else {
    ls.set("myList", [media])
     window.location.reload(false)
  
  }

 }

 const RemoveFromList = (mediaId) => {
  
  let newlist = []
   let myList = ls("myList")
    myList.filter((items) => {
    if(items.id !== mediaId.id){
       newlist.push(items)
     }
   })
  
   ls("myList", newlist)
   setWatchlist(newlist)
 }
```

When I click the button to add a movie to the watch list I want it to check if the movie is already in Local storage , if it is I don't want it to add that same movie again. I want my local storage to be like a set containing unique items. The issue I have now is im putting the same movie more than once in local storge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const addToMyList = (media) => {
// Heres where i add my data 
  let myList;
  if(ls("myList") !== null){
    myList = ls("myList")
    myList.push(media)
    ls.set("myList", myList)
    setWatchlist(myList)
   
    
  } else {
    ls.set("myList", [media])
     window.location.reload(false)
  
  }

 }
```

in the above mentioned method whenever you are trying to add new media first check if media is already present in localStorage or not

```
    const findMedia = myList.find(x => x === media)
    if(!findMedia) {
      myList.push(media);
      myList.push(media)
      ls.set("myList", myList)
      setWatchlist(myList)
    }
```